# Identify revision of an export from Subversion?

Tags: svn, export, revision

concerning version control, SVN specifically, how would I identify the revision an export was exported from whithout knowing who exported it or when it was exported?

I've checked SVN-keywords but they don't seem to do what I want.

Creating a file that holds the revision number and distributing that along with the export seems unsafe to me, too, since that file could be manipulated or deleted.

So is there some way to compare the actual files with the ones in version control to determine a revision number? (or any other reliable way, for that matter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `svn export` removes the connectivity of source with subversion; Subversion won't be of any help.

All you could do is to keep version number in a file, as you said, and use that as an indicator.

Comment: After all, this seems like the only solution... Even if I don't like it.

Comment: same here mate. Even i don't like it.